# Package depreciation and evaluating your ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am going to be giving a quick demo for work, and I am running into this error message on the code that I had prepared earlier:

> "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:395:
>   DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17
>   and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
>   X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1)
>   if it contains a single sample.   DeprecationWarning)"

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
x = ml_list # This variable will refer to your features 
y = labels # This variable will refer to your labels
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5) 


#Evaluating Decision Tree Classifier
my_classifier_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_classifier_tree.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions_tree = my_classifier_tree.predict(x_test)
print(predictions_tree)
```

What should I do to get my code to run again?

Comment: That is not an error, its just a warning. You should show in which line you are getting the warning. Also, it can be solved as described in the warning message.

Comment: Looking at the list, seems like your `x` is a list. Does it contain a single feature only? If yes, do `x=x.reshape(-1,1)`.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for getting back. The feature contains a list in this format: "[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6]". Label is either "0" or "1". I am not able to pinpoint where exactly this error is popping up at.

Comment: This is feature of one sample? Then use `x=x.reshape(-1, 6)` and see if warning goes away.

Comment: @VivekKumar I am getting an error that "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape' ".

Comment: Yes. Then use `import numpy as np` and `x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 6)`.

Comment: @VivekKumar When I run it like that, I am back to the same error message that I started with.